# Perl nested loops

Tags: perl, loops, file-io

I have a text file with the following contents:

```
NW1 SN1 DEV1
NW2 SN1 DEV2
```

I wrote a Perl script to iterate over the file, but it is running only once. The code is:

```
open(INPUT1,"input.txt");
@input_array = <INPUT1>;

for($i=0;$i<@input_array;$i++)
{
    my ($ser,$node,@dev)=split(/ +/,$input_array[$i]);

    for($x=0;$x<@dev;$x++)
    {
        print("Hi");
    }
}
```

The script is iterating for the first line but not iterating for second line.

Comment: the file is like  first line  NW1 SN1  DEV1 second line NW1  SN1 DEV2

Comment: Well your program prints `HiHi` (two times "Hi") which looks fine to me. The code is printing "Hi" for every "DEV" on every line and there are two lines with one "DEV" in each line. If you want to print each "Hi" on its own line you have to append a newline (`\n`) like `print "Hi\n";` - otherwise, could you please tell us what output you expect?

Comment: hey thanks its working fine now ..mistake with the way i am taking in input array ...i am using while now ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted could be improved, and brought up to more modern standards.

- It uses a bareword filehandle `INPUT1`.
- It doesn't use 3-arg [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).
- It doesn't use [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) or [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064509/why-not-use-strict-and-warnings-in-perl)).
- It doesn't check the return value of [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) or [`close`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html). ( That's what the [autodie](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) line is for in the following code )
- It uses C-style [for loops](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops) when it doesn't need to.
- It loads the entire file into memory even though it only deals with the file one line at a time.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie; # checks return value of open and close for us

# 3 arg open
open( my $in_fh, '<', 'input.txt' );

# don't read the file into memory until needed
while( <$in_fh> ){
    # using $_ simplified this line
    my ($ser,$node,@dev) = split;

    # no need to track the indices just loop over the array
    for my $dev (@dev){
        print "Hi\n";
    }
}

close $in_fh;
```

If for some reason you really did need the indices of the `@dev` array it would be better to write it like this:

```
for my $x ( 0..$#dev ){
  ...
}
```

If you want to explicitly store the line into a variable of a different name, you would change the `while` loop to this:

```
while( my $line = <$in_fh> ){
    my ($ser,$node,@dev) = split / +/ $line;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You forgot to enter to slurp mode of the '<>' operator. To suck in complete file you should do this:

```
open(INPUT1,"input.txt");
undef $/;
@input_array = split(/\r?\n/, <INPUT1>);
close INPUT1;
```

or better yet like this:

```
open(INPUT1,"input.txt");
while(<INPUT1>) {
  chomp;
  my ($ser,$node,@dev)=split(/ +/,$_);  

  for($x=0;$x<@dev;$x++) 
  {
    print("Hi");
  }
}
close INPUT1;
```

Comment: Assigning `<>` to a list will read the whole file, as an array of lines. Granted, the code with `while` is definitely more scalable and idiomatic for this scenario.